# How to make Raspberry Pi OS fileysystem truly read-only (SHA512 checksum of SD card after rebooting is identical)

Tags: filesystems, debian

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/nicokaiser/08aa5b7b3958f171cf61549b70e8a34b) guide and, in theory, the filesystem is read-only.

```
$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=5838cc20-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 fastboot fsck.mode=skip noswap ro systemd.volatile=state

$ cat /etc/fstab
proc                  /proc proc  defaults                    0 0
PARTUUID=5838cc20-01  /boot vfat  defaults,ro                 0 2
PARTUUID=5838cc20-02  /     ext4  defaults,noatime,ro,noload  0 1
```

That being said, I noticed that the SHA512 checksum of the SD card changes after rebooting.

Someone on unix.stackexchange.com [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637270/362818) that it could be due to journaling and that disabling it using `noload` should help, but the SHA512 checksum of the SD card still changes after rebooting.

**Edit:** I believe the `/boot` partition is responsible for the inconsistent SHA512 checksum.

I am probably naively thinking that running a truly read-only filesystem (such as Tails) is easily configurable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

macOS was adding hidden files and/or folders (`.fseventsd`, `.DS_Store` and/or `.Spotlight-V100`) to `boot` volume.

Running the following to disable auto-mount of `boot` volume on macOS fixed the issue.

```
volume_path="/Volumes/boot"
volume_uuid=`diskutil info "$volume_path" | awk '/Volume UUID:/ { print $3 }'`
echo "UUID=$volume_uuid none msdos rw,noauto" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as accepte dwhen it's possible

Comment: @MechMK1 Thanks for the heads-up... will do.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your SD card is only "readonly" from the software side. root can always change that and could even go to lower levels like the SD cards firmware. For trve/better readonlyness you need to go to lower levels, ideally the flash itself.

There is also some kind of firmware(hardware?) version of write protection for SD cards:
https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool

But I don't know how reliable that really is. Afaik there is not much research on it.

From the description here:

https://mvidakovic.blogspot.com/2019/08/the-ultimate-read-only-file-system-on.html

It sounds like the device could be protected at the hardware level (which would be great). Or when using the WP bit the firmware still does not tell the OS it is readonly, for whatever reason.

Comment: Great contribution, thanks! I am aware this approach operates at the software layer. This is why I use SHA512 hashes to make sure the content of the SD card has not changed between uses.

Comment: I will look up the tool you mentioned... didn't know about this!

Comment: For emmc: Looks like the WP bit implementation depends on the manufacturer and could possibly be reset (including data loss?) and/or needs physical access: https://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f296/how-fix-emmc-readonly-2045084/ https://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f609/samsung-emmc-write-protection-removal-1921517/